# Declare a null var in Scala

Tags: scala, null, var

I have read that `null` should not be used in scala.

How can I leave `myVar` uninitialized without the use of `null`?

```
class TestClass {

    private var myVar: MyClass = null

}
```

I understand I can just make a dummy `MyClass`, that is never used in place of the `null`.  But this can and does reduce the code's understandability.

As Rado has explained I can change `null` as shown below.  I understand that I can now check to see if the variable is set during run-time, however, if I don't program that check then there is no benefit of using Option in this case.

Coming from Java, I feel there should be a way to simply leave the var uninitialized at compile-time and let it set during run-time without using the Option class, because as I mentioned above, if I don't code for the unset case then why use Option?

```
class TestClass {

    private var myVar: Option[MyClass] = None

    private def createVar() {
        myVar = Some(new MyClass)

        x: MyClass = myVar.get

    }
}
```

I am thinking the only other way of doing what I am asking is:

```
class TestClass {

    // Using dummy MyClass that will never be used.
    private var myVar: MyClass = new MyClass

    private def process(myVar: MyClass) {
        this.myVar = myVar

        myVar.useVarMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Rado Buransky's answer, and instead of checking if(myVar == null), you have to check if(myVar.isDefined){val local = myvar.get}. I think you are expecting this kind of coding style.

Comment: @SKarthik Rather, I am expecting that the var is set, always. So I should never have to check for it.  In the case it wasn't set then I would let the tests/run-time print the error because this would imply a coding error.  But having the myVar set is not an option, it is a requirement.

Comment: if that is the case, you can just write myVar.get, wherever you are using myVar. This will give you None.get Exception, instead of NullPointer Excepion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Scala way is to declare the variable as `Option[MyClass]`:

```
class TestClass {
   private var myVar: Option[MyClass] = None

   private def createVar() {
     myVar = Some(new MyClass)
  }

  // Usage example:
  def useMyVar(): Unit = {
    myVar match {
      case Some(myClass) => {
        // Use myClass here ...
        println(myClass.toString)
      }
      case None => // What to do if myVar is undefined?
    }
  }
}
```

That way you avoid NullPointerException. You make it explicit that the variable can be in undefined state. Everytime you use the `myVar` you have to define what to do if it is undefined.
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option

Comment: But then when I initialize it, it has to be of type Option[MyClass] instead of MyClass.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the point. If it can be undefined (null) throught the variable's lifecycle, then make it explicit. Perhaps try to provide more detailed example so that we can figure out a better solution.

Comment: Updated. You have to use `Some(...)`. But even better way would be to make the `TestClass` immutable, but that's out of scope of this question...

Comment: But myVar's Type is still Option[MyClass]

Comment: I've updated the example to show you how to use it if it's Option[]

Comment: Rado, I am uncertain why using Option would prevent run-time exceptions if I don't program to check if the var is unset.  Please see my new edits.

Comment: Of course if you use `get` and the value is not set, then you'll get an exception. You should always use safe methods to access the value if it's there. It depends on what you want to do. One typical way is to use `match` or `map`.

Comment: For this particular case I am going to use null since I will not need to do any error checking.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rado, it was very informative and I will put it to use.

Answer (score 2):

> I need myVar to be of type MyClass not Option[MyClass]. I see that I
>   could use Rado's updated answer and then use the get method, but is
>   there any other way?

When you use `Option` you can telling the compiler and everyone else who will read/use your code that it's okay not to define this value and the code will handle that condition and not fail at runtime.

The other way of dealing with is to do null checks every time before you access the variable because it could be `null` and therefore throw an exception at **runtime**.

When you use `Option`, the compiler will tell you if at **compile time** that you have not handled a condition where the value of a variable maybe undefined.

If you think about it, it's really a big deal. you have converted a runtime exception (which is deterministic) to a compile-time error.

Comment: The code can handle the condition of an unset var, but it does not if I don't code for it.  This would result in a runtime exception, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the value out of something like an Option (which supports map and also flatMap), then you don't necessarily have to keep doing pattern matching on whether or not the Option contains a value (i.e. is a "Some") or not (i.e. is a "None").

Two methods are very useful - if you want just alter (or "map") the value within the Option then you can use the map method, which takes a function with a general type of:

```
f: A => B
```

so in your case at compile time would end up being:

```
f: MyClass => B
```

When you map an option, if the option is a "Some" then the contained value is passed through to the mapping function, and the function is applied (to change the MyClass to a B if you like...) and the result is passed back wrapped in an Option.  If your Option is a None, then you just get a None back.

Here's a simple example:

```
scala> case class MyClass(value : String)
defined class MyClass

scala> val emptyOption : Option[MyClass] = None
emptyOption: Option[MyClass] = None

scala> val nonEmptyOption = Some(new MyClass("Some value"))
nonEmptyOption: Option[MyClass] = Some(MyClass(Some value)
```

Try and extract the value from both option instances using map:

```
scala> nonEmptyOption map { s => s.value + " mapped" }
res10: Option[String] = Some(Some value mapped)

scala> emptyOption map { s => s.value }
res11: Option[String] = None
```

So basically, if you map across an empty option, you always get a None. Map across a non-empty Option and you can extract the contained value and transform it and get the result wrapped back in an Option.  Notice that you don't need to explicitly check any patterns...the map method takes care of it.

Flatmap is a bit more challenging to explain, but it basically isn't massively different except that it takes a function which has type:

```
g: A => M[B]
```

which basically allows you to take the value out of the Option (the 'A' in the type signature above), do something to it (i.e. a computation) and then return the result ('B') - *wrapped* in another container such as another Option, List...

The same notion (across Option anyway) that if the Option is a None then nothing really happens still applies.  flatMap and map form the basis of Scala "for comprehensions" which you can read about (and are done far more justice than I could!!) in lots of other places.

Comment: What benefit is there to using a map when I could extract the value with nonEmptyOption.get ?

Comment: Usage of map and flatMap methods allows you to write more "idiomatic" code.  Map and flatMap effectively allow you to get at what's inside the option (if it exists) and then do something with this value all in one method call, so you don't have to have any explicit pattern matching.  I guess it's a matter of personal taste, but usage of map and flatMap can lead to much cleaner code...IMO